# Developing Facebook App for large API request load?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was given a task to post on Facebook fan pages through Graph API. I have successfully managed to do it. Everything is running fine from my end.

We are managing about 2000-3000 fan pages from 3 or 4 profiles. We post about 15000-20000 posts daily on Facebook fan pages.

One big problem is, after some days (5-6 days), our App is deleted or blocked by Facebook or App developer account is blocked or profile account is blocked.

Our App is properly configured and all Facebook required details have been entered in App details like privacy policy, terms of services, website/domain, etc. We are not posting any content that violates the Facebook policy.

I have Googled a lot to find the right solution but couldn't find one. I have visited some commercial websites offering same sort of services.
These commercial websites post million of posts every day.

- I am very eager to know how they maintain App, App profiles, etc?
- What is the right solution to maintain such Apps?
- Is there anything special Facebook offer for such Apps?

We have Facebook business manager account (business.facebook.com). Can this help to solve this issue?

Feel free to ask any question regarding this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is your app approved? did you go through login review? 2000-3000 fan pages is a LOT, what are those pages about exactly?

Comment: Apps in the commercial markets maintain more than 10,000 pages. Our  pages belong to fashion niche. Like make-up, dresses, etc. @luschn

Comment: Check https://developers.facebook.com/appeal if the app is listed there. If so, appeal and ask them why they blocked the app. // What is the content of those “about 15000-20000 posts” you make daily – are those all individual posts, or are you posting the same stuff to a lot of pages? If the latter, Facebook’s machine learning system might be more inclined to think it is spam.

Comment: Our niche is Fashion like dresses, makeup, nail arts, etc. Only related stuff is posted. 2nd part of your comment seems quite valid. A single post is posted on 150-200 fan pages pages. As **thepiyush13** said App and profile rate limit is also a issue. So seems multiple issue. What you suggest in this scenario? @CBroe

Comment: _“A single post is posted on 150-200 fan pages”_ – that could be problematic. Even if it was not the reason your app got banned, it is still likely to result in less news feed distribution – because if Facebook detects that the same content is posted to multiple pages, and maybe even at about the same time, they might be tempted to see that as spam. Only thing I can suggest, is to make the posts more individual/unique, more tailored to the specific page …

Comment: Is there a way to get the user API call limit through API? @CBroe

Comment: No, not that I’m aware of. Facebook will just respond with an error once you reached the limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explore more about facebook API limits, on the developer page it says :

> Each each app is given an allotment of 200 API calls per user in any
>   given 60 minute window.
>
> As an example, if your app had 10 users yesterday and 5 new logins
>   today, that would give you a base of 15 users. This means that your
>   app can make ((10 + 5) * 200) = 3000 API calls in any 60 minute
>   window.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting

Repetedly violating API limits can get your app stopped or worse deleted

Comment: Thanks for your Facebook link, I take a look and get back. @thepiyush13

Comment: I have read the limit but in my case I am not receiving error code 4 or 17 or any other. Facebook is not limiting the App or profile by imposing limit. If Facebook returns error it can easily be traced. I am also surprised by reading this 200 API call limits per 60 minutes. In this case, it will take weeks to post huge data like commercial App in the market do but they post in a single day. Still surprised. @thepiyush13

Comment: Is there a way to get the user API call limit through API? @thepiyush13